# Firebase AppCheck does not work with Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-run, invisible-recaptcha, firebase-app-check

I am using Firebase Appcheck and RecaptchaV3 Provider in a web app. All works fine on localhost (both with debug token and NOT recommended way - setting localhost to allowed Domains at RecaptchaV3). The web app local deployment is done with Docker. When I deploy exactly the same image to Cloud Run it does not work.
Production deployment process:

1. Deploy the web app Docker image on Cloud run ✓
   [image]
2. Add my custom domain to domain mapping on Cloud run ✓
   [image]
3. Set the mapped domain and also URL of my Cloud Run to allowed domains on Recaptcha page.  ✓
   [image]
4. Now, when I open the web app, I am getting `{code: 403, message: "Requests from referer https://development.mydomain.xx/ are blocked.",…}`
   [image]

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong? I can provide any additional info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that I set an API restriction for the API key. The solution was to add my domain to the allowed domain section in APIs and services.
[image]